# How do you run LinSched simulator?

Tags: linux

I'm a novice in linux and I'm doing a project on scheduling. I installed the LinSched
on my PC to see the behavior of "LinSched" and how it works? I followed the steps given in the link 
[Scheduler simulator linsched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824652/scheduler-simulator-linsched)
but I could not make it work. Am I supposed to copy "Listing 4" from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linux-scheduler-simulator/
and write it in basic_test.c? Also I found difficulties in step 5 and step 6.